# Check if None in nested list

Tags: python, list, nested, python-itertools, nonetype

How to find a None in a nested listed. When I run the following code, the Hello is not printed. I do not know how to spot a None in the list of a list. Can you please help me with this simple question.

```
myList = [[0,1,2],[5,None,300]]

if None in myList:

print("Hello")
```

Comment: I would expect if the indentation is really like this that you'd get an error on that if statement.

Comment: Are you just trying to find this, or did you need the data manipulated in some way as well?

Comment: As the answers are pointing out, you need to iterate over a list inside your myList - "for list in myList", and then check for None in the resultant 'list'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solutions! I was using the right indendation but I did not know how to iterate over list of lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use any:

```
myList = [[0,1,2],[5,None,300]]
if any(None in l for l in myList):
    print("Hello")
```

Or `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
if None in chain(*myList):
    print("Hello")
```

Answer (score 4):

This is basically a special case of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/364696); you need to flatten it to perform the test. In this case, the best approach is to use `itertools.chain` to do the flattening, which allows you to use the `in` testing in a short-circuiting manner (it stops when it finds a `None`, no work is done for elements after it):

```
from itertools import chain

myList = [[0,1,2],[5,None,300]]

if None in chain.from_iterable(myList):
    print("Hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, pay attention to indentation:

```
for inner_list in myList:
   for item in inner_list:
      if item is None:
         print('hello')
```

Comment: it item is 0 this will print hello

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = [[0,1,2],[5,None,300]]

for x in myList:
    if None in x:
        print("Hello")
```

Note that this will print once for every "None" found.